# Why can't I foreach through my ViewData or Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ienumerable

I keep getting errors trying to iterate through my ViewData in the view there... I even tried strongly typing the view to IEnumerable(App.Models.Namespace) and using Model, to no avail. Either I get an error for lack of a GetEnumerable method or invalid type casting... Any idea how I do this?

Model...

```
public IQueryable<Product> getAllProducts()
{
    return (from p in db.Products select p);
}
```

Controller...

```
public ActionResult Pricing()
{
    IQueryable<Product> products = orderRepository.getAllProducts();

    ViewData["products"] = products.ToList();

    return View();
}
```

View...

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Pricing
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Pricing</h2>

    <div>
        <select class="product">
            <%foreach(var prod in ViewData["products"]){%>
                <option><%=prod.Title %></option>
            <%} %>

        </select><select></select>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this with the cast:

```
foreach(var prod in (List<Product>)ViewData["products"])
```

Comment: Find out what ViewData["products"] really is by outputting
 ViewData["products"].GetType().FullName

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (var prod in (ViewData["products"] as IEnumerable<Product>))
```

I got into a similar situation and this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing it like this anyway? Why not do:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Product>>
```

in your view.  Then in your controller action do:

```
public ActionResult Pricing()
{
    IQueryable<Product> products = orderRepository.getAllProducts();
    return View(products.ToList(););
}
```

Then you don't have to use `ViewData` at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%foreach(Product prod in ViewData["products"]){%>
```

Comment: The `var` is an implicit type declaration and means you don't have to know the exact type of the variable when you're writing the code.

Comment: Right, but only when the returning result is an exact type. In the case of ViewData, I'm pretty sure it returns an Object that must be cast. Foreach is doing the cast for you

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(var prod in ViewData["products"] as IQueryable<Product>)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting list from more than two model and want to show two model in one list than you should use like this..
Create your two model first is Student and second is Teacher.

```
// Create Models
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public List<int> Marks { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

//Create controller

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Student> students = new List<Student>()
        {
            new Student {Id = 1, Name = "Vikas", Address = "Mohali", Marks = new List<int> {90, 23, 46,56} },
            new Student {Id = 2, Name = "Rajeev", Address = "Mohali", Marks = new List<int> { 56, 78, 34, 67 }},
            new Student {Id = 3, Name = "Ajay", Address = "Delhi", Marks = new List<int> {56, 78, 34, 56}}
        };

        List<Teacher> teachers = new List<Teacher>()
        {
            new Teacher {Id = 1, Name = "Arun Nagar", Address = "Delhi"},
            new Teacher {Id = 2, Name = "Manish Kumar", Address = "Mohali"}
        };

        var Querylist = (from student in students
                         where student.Address == "Mohali"
                         select student.Name)
                        .Concat(from teacher in teachers
                                where teacher.Address == "Mohali"
                                select teacher.Name);
        //get list in ViewBag
        ViewBag.DataLIst = Querylist;
        //get list in View Data
        ViewData["DataLIst1"] = Querylist.ToList();
        return View(Querylist.AsEnumerable());
    }

//create View "Index.cshtml"   


@foreach (var h in @ViewBag.DataLIst)
{ 
    <h3>@h</h3>
}
@foreach (var s in @ViewData["DataLIst1"] as List< string>)
{
    <h1>@s</h1>
}
```